# Using Azure B2C to authenticate users for access to microservices behind API management

Tags: azure, microservices, azure-ad-b2c, azure-api-management

How do I use Azure B2C with API Management to authenticate access to backend microservices.

I've checked a couple of links, which confuse me, see this link, it talks about authorizing developer accounts by using AAD B2C, but does not tell how to authenticate end users 
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-aad-b2c

I am creating an Architecture where I have a couple of microservices behind Azure API Management, I want to authenticate users through B2C before the request hits API management. Once the request is authenticated, I am assuming B2C will provide a JWT token which the API management will validate and then give access to the backend microservices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-aad-b2c) you referred to is authorizing developer accounts.

You should refer to this document. This also applies to Azure AD B2C.

[Protect an API by using OAuth 2.0 with Azure Active Directory and API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad)

Comment: Totally makes sense for Azure AD, was hoping to find some relevant documentation for B2C. I guess this should work. Thanks